# Disjoint Lite Feedback Vertex Set

Tags: algorithms, parameterized-complexity

Disjoint Lite Feedback Vertex Set. given an undirected graph G and k ∈ N, and a Lite Feedback Vertex Set(LFVS) X of G of size ≤k+1 the objective is to decide whether there exists a subset S ⊆ V (G) of size at most k that is disjoint from X and that every connected component in G − S is either a tree or a simple cycle.

(Lite Feedback Vertex Set, given an undirected graph G and k ∈ N the objective is to decide whether there exists a subset S ⊆ V (G) of size at most k that every connected component in  G − S is either a tree or a simple cycle.)

I am trying to find a solution for Disjoint Lite Feedback Vertex set with O(3^k*n^o(1)) run time.

Comment: OK. So what's your question? Note that no SE site is a homework service. We are happy to help if you provide reasonable effort and ask a clear, focused question.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/141786/755

Comment: What's the context where you encountered this task?  As [others have mentioned](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/142176/lite-feedback-vertex-set#comment299335_142176), we require you to credit the original source of all copied material.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.